# Jquery .html returning function string

Tags: jquery, sql, function

Situation: I am using a Jquery .insertAtCaret function to populate several text boxes from a database. The user is then able to confirm/edit the values before 'saving' the current values back to the database.

```
/*Input emergency into text area*/

$('#emergInstructor').insertAtCaret(emergInstructor);
$('#emergStudent').insertAtCaret(emergStudent);
$('#emergDate').insertAtCaret(datetoday);
$('#emergEmergency').insertAtCaret(emergEmergency);

/*Save current values into Database*/
$("#savesetup").click(function() {  
var setupinstructor = $("#emergInstructor:text").text();
var setupstudent = $("#emergStudent:text").text();
var setupemergency = $("#emergEmergency:text").text();
var today = Date.today().toString('d-MMM-yyyy');
var setupperformance = $("#performance:selected").text();
var setupcomments = $("#comments:text").text();
var setupsql = "INSERT INTO fullemerghistory (instructor, student, emergency, datey, performance, comments) VALUES('"+ setupinstructor +"', '"+ setupstudent +"', '"+ setupemergency+ "', '"+ today +"', '"+ setupperformance +"', '"+ setupcomments +"')";
    if(myDB.query(setupsql)) {
        alert("Inserted!");
     }


 });
```

Problem: The INSERT statement is trying to add a string of a function some of which is below (its pretty long!):

```
'function(e){return y.access(this,function(e){var n=this[0]||{},r=0,i=this.length;if(e===t)return n.nodeType===1?n.innerHTML.replace(pt,""):t;if(typeof e=="string"&&!wt.test(e)&&(y.support.htmlSerialize||!dt.test(e))&&(y.support.leadingWhitespace||!vt.test(e))&&!Ct[(gt.exec(e)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()]){e=e.replace(mt,"<$1>");try{for(;r
```

Question: I believe that the insertAtCaret function is the problem, however I do not know where to start. What I want is to populate the database with the current values in the text areas.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly are you using `.html`? Where are you defining `emergInstructor`? you've likely left a `()` off somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for reply. emergInstructor is defined by: `$.each(emergjson, function(key, value) {
  window.emergInstructor = value.instructor;
  window.emergStudent = value.student;
  window.emergEmergency = value.emergency;
 });` where emergjson is a Json array pulled from a database. Ill look into the () issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

I changed the Jquery selectors and used the .val function:

```
$("#savesetup").click(function() {  
var setupinstructor = $('#emergInstructor').val();
var setupstudent = $('#emergStudent').val();
var setupemergency = $('#emergEmergency').val();
var today = Date.today().toString('d-MMM-yyyy');
var setupperformance = $('#performance').val();
var setupcomments = $('#comments').val()
 )};
```

Thanks to KevinB for a nudge in the right direction.